# Make a call to Amazon LEX asynchronously

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, python-asyncio, amazon-lex

I have working code to call Amazon Lex and get a response from a bot. Here is a snippet of the code:

```
client = boto3.client(
    'lexv2-runtime', 
    region_name=region_name, 
    aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
    aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key
)

    response = client.recognize_text(
        botId=bot_id,
        botAliasId=bot_alias_id,
        localeId='en_US',
        sessionId=session_id,
        text=user_message,
    )
```

I now want to make this call be async. How do I achieve that using boto3 or any other python library that is supported by Amazon Lex

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it `RecognizeTextAsync` is only available in the DotNet SDK. It is, therefore, not available in the Python, Java or JavaScript SDK's.

You would need to wrap your boto3 call with an asynch library. I have no experience with the below, but it might be the answer to solving your problem.

https://pypi.org/project/aioboto3/

Comment: Thanks, I will trythisone out but it does seem to support other service like s3 and not amazon lex

Answer (score 0):

Got this working with [aiboto3](https://github.com/terrycain/aioboto3)

```
    async with session.client('lexv2-runtime', region_name=region_name, aws_access_key_id=access_key_id,
                              aws_secret_access_key=secret_access_key) as client:
        response = await client.recognize_text(
            botId=bot_id,
            botAliasId=bot_alias_id,
            localeId='en_US',
            sessionId=session_id,
            text="hi",
        )
```